# segfault connecting tcl to C++ and calling a virtual method

Tags: c++, tcl

I'm seeing some behaviour I can't explain in a legacy C++ application with communication interfaces implemented in TCL via a bridge. I don't know much about TCL and I don't know if it is relevant the problem.

I have a callback method that takes a TCL ClientData object, the TCL interpreter and a standard argc/argv pair. The ClientData can be cast to a pointer to a type defined in my application, `TclOb`. `TclOb` is a virtual base class, but none of the sub-classes override the virtual method I want to call.

```
int TclCallBack(ClientData clientdata, Tcl_Interp* interp, int argc, const char** argv)
{
    // ok - pointer is good
    TclOb* ob = static_cast<TclOb*>(clientdata);
    int result;

    // ok - runs method fine
    result = ob->nonvirtualMethod();

    // segfault
    result = ob->virtualmethod();
    ::debug("we never get here");
    return result;
}
```

The `TclOb` class is fairly complicated virtual base class but a minimal example might look like this:

```
class TclOb {
public:
    TclOb() {}
    virtual ~TclOb() {}

    int nonvirtualMethod() {
        ::debug("got into the non-virtual method");
        return 1;
    }

    virtual int virtualMethod() {
        ::debug("we never get into the virtual method");
        return 1; 
    }
};
```

As far as I can tell, this crash started happening when we removed the `-m32` compiler flags from the build and improved the portability of an unrelated part of the application. We found this issue while doing surgery on the build system so it will be difficult to go back and figure out where it changed and exactly what the cause was.

Has anyone encountered this before? I'm struggling to get my head around it.

**Update:** I've not been able to get anywhere with a debugger or Valgrind as this application is started by and communicated with only via TCL scripts, making it tricky to plug into it and get any useful data out.

Comment: "ClientData can be cast to a pointer to a type " - apparently not. Out of curiosity, what does your debugger highlight when the wheels fall off ? Fyi, compilers typically just make non-virtual method calls a direct function call after pushing a `this` (no need for vtable lookup). As such, the running non-virtual function may well think life is grand, and as long as it can read/write on what it thinks are member data locations, it just marches on. a vtable-method-call, on the other hand, obviously relies on a valid vtable, and is more prone to blow up early. I'd start validating your objects.

Comment: Usually `ClientData` is just a typedef for `void*` and set when you call one of the `Tcl_CreateCommand` familiy of functions. It could also get modified with `Tcl_SetCommandInfo`. So check what gets passed to your creation command.

Comment: Tcl's API promise for a `ClientData` is that it is the size of a raw pointer (`void*`) and that Tcl won't try to look inside what it means; it will just pass it around. What is `sizeof(ClientData)` and `sizeof(TclOb*)` on your problem platform? If the C++ compiler has decided to make the pointer to the class larger, that'd be what the immediate problem is…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got to the bottom of this.

It turns out that I had tried to *fix* a memory leak by using RAII where the existing code new'ed a pointer to some object before passing it off to the TCL interpreter. After that point, TCL manages the lifetime of the memory, so using RAII to clean up was causing the interpreter to dereference a freed pointer, leading to a segmentation fault.

The solution was to revert the change and document the pointer with a stern warning to any future developers about the number of hours wasted trying to *fix* the non-issue.